# ReactJS event handler update state of dictionary value

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write a event handle for few input box and I realize that it's not able to update the state of the dict. if I change it to string it works fine.

**if I change state to following it works fine.**

```
this.state = {          
        firstName: "",
        lastName: ""    
}
```

**However following doesn't**

```
import React, {Component} from "react"

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            list: {
                firstName: "",
                lastName: ""    
            }

        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        console.log(name)
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    value={this.state.firstName} 
                    name="list[firstName]" 
                    placeholder="First Name" 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                />
                <br />
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    value={this.state.lastName} 
                    name="list[lastName]" 
                    placeholder="Last Name" 
                    onChange={this.handleChange} 
                />

                <h1>{this.state.firstName} {this.state.lastName}</h1>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're correctly destructuring the `name` and `value` props from `event.target` in your `handleChange` function, BUT the `name` properties you set on your two `<input>` elements are not intuitive. Your `name` properties are currently `"list[firstName]"` and `"list[lastName]"` -> this won't reach into your `this.state.list[firstName]` / `this.state.list[lastName]` properties as you wish - instead, you should change your `name` properties to reflect your `state` values, like this:

```
<input
    name="firstName"
    {/* other props stay the same... */}
/>
<input
    name="lastName"
    {/* other props stay the same... */}
/>
```

Now that your `<input>` elements have `name` properties that also match values on your `state`, you can change your `handleChange` function to something like this:

```
handleChange(event) {
    // get name and value properties from event target
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        // update your 'list' property
        list: {
          // spread old values into this object so you don't lose any data
          ...prevState.list,
          // update this field's value
          [name]: value
        }
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `handleChange` function you can change setState to following:

```
this.setState({
      list: {
        [name]: value
      }
    })
// in input
value={this.state.list.firstName}
```

Answer (score 2):

The second case does not work because there are flaws. So to make your code run you need to make two changes in your input field

1) `name="list[firstName]"` as `name="firstName"`

2) `value={this.state.firstName}` as `value={this.state.list.firstName}`

If you use `name="list[firstName]"` in your input field then whenever `[name]: value` in `handleChange` method executes, it evaluates to `['list[firstName]']: value` and it will create another property `list[firstName]` in the state.

i.e `state = { list: {...}, list[firstName]: value }`.

So it won't update the property `firstName` inside the `list` as you expect.

**For more detail:** [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

And using `value={this.state.list.firstName}` we can map state `list.firstName` with the input field

```
    <input 
            type="text" 
            // do not use value={this.state.firstName} 
            value={this.state.list.firstName} 
            // do not use name="list[firstName]"
            name="firstName" 
            placeholder="First Name" 
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
    />

    <input 
            type="text" 
            value={this.state.list.lastName} 
            name="lastName" 
            placeholder="Last Name" 
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
    />
```

In your `handleChange` method, your are trying to update the property `firstName` and `lastName` inside `list`.

So to do that first you need to use `list` inside `this.setState` method as `this.setState({ list: {...}})`.

As `list` is an object and you want to update specific property of `list` so first you need to copy all properties inside the `list` using spread operator. And then after that you can change the property you want to change using dynamic / computed property. So change your `handleChange` method to

```
handleChange(event) {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        this.setState({
            list: {
              // copy all properties inside the "list" 
              // so that we change only the property 
              // we need to change and keep other properties as it is
              ...this.state.list,
              // dynamically changing property
              [name]: value
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer

Comment: This is what I am trying to say, use static string as `name-"firstname`. JSX doesn't transform into setting state using something dynamic inside static string.